# Column in table not being filled

Tags: php, html-table

This is driving me crazy. The table renders correctly in that the column headers are all correct and the first column is correct but then the second column is skipped and the data that should be there is in the 3rd column and the 3rd in the 4th column etc. When I look at the page source everything looks correct. But when I look at "elements" in Chrome's developers tools there is the extra . Here is the code:

```
echo '<table id="bordered">';
                echo '<thead>';
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<th></th>';
                        foreach($products as $product){
                            /*@var $product Products */
                            echo '<th>',$product->getProductName(),'</th>';
                        }
                    echo '</tr>';
                echo '</thead>';
                echo '<tbody>';
                    foreach($customers as $cust){
                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>',$cust->getCustomerName(),'<td>';
                            $prod = ForecastDisplay_db::getProductsQuantityForCustomer($cust, $products);
                            $i=0;
                            foreach($prod as $quantity){
                                $i++;
                                if($i == 1){
                                    echo '<td>First Run</td>';
                                }else{
                                    echo '<td>', $quantity['id'],'  ',$quantity['quantity'],'</td>';
                                }
                            }
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                echo '</tbody>';
            echo '</table>';
```

I added that 'First Run' to make sure there wasn't a null in the first positions of the array's but there isn't. Anyone have an idea why that column is being skipped?

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($prod)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not closed the `td` tag correctly.

```
echo '<td>',$cust->getCustomerName(),'<td>';
```

should be

```
echo '<td>',$cust->getCustomerName(),'</td>';
```

Comment: Holy stupid. I stared at this thing for over an hour and completely missed it. Thanks!